# Can I have multiple URLs map to an Action, changing a boolean parameter?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have a spring (3.1) controller action method like this:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/{id}")
public String myAction(@PathVariable("id") long someId) { ... }
```

I want to introduce a boolean:

```
public String myAction(@PathVariable("id") long someId, boolean doBranch) { ... }
```

However, I want the boolean to be set based on which URL the method is accessed. In other words, I want

```
/foo/123 => myAction(123,false)
/debug/foo/123 => myAction(123,true)
```

I know I can add multiple urls to the RequestMapping annotation, but I haven't seen a way to have the mapping itself impact a parameter, short of passing in the parameter or course (`/foo/123?doBranch=true"`).

Can I somehow easily extend Spring to do that? Or is there something already in there that would do that?

Comment: what us your end goal? this sounds like a bad idea ...

Comment: @les2 I want to have some methods return extra information or diagnostic information, and have that on a different URL to clearly segregate the "namespace". That being said, security isn't a concern here, just clean URLs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I know this isn't the most elegant way but:

```
@RequestMapping("/foo/{id}")
public String myActionA(@PathVariable("id") long someId) {
   return myAction(someId, true);
}
@RequestMapping("/debug/foo/{id}")
public String myActionB(@PathVariable("id") long someId) {
   return myAction(someId, false);
}

public String myAction(@PathVariable("id") long someId, boolean doBranch) { ... }
```

Simply map the URLs to 2 different methods that call a third method with either `true` or `false`.

Comment: I agree with @jjinguy, sometimes the simplest solution is just providing some facade methods.  The facade method approach also lends the "debug" variant to potentially perform other logic (logging, etc) before/after the common "myAction" method is called